# populating select options dynamically javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have option for select list dynamically.
I want to populate select list for year values dynamically using java script.
It should be current year to next 10 years as drop down, any idea?

```
<form action="something">
  some other fields
  <select id="year">
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: @brenjt no way this is my website which of course has this form, this is credit card form whcih has cvv and expiration date which has year option to select, comeon:-(

Comment: Just have to ask cause a lot of students ask for homework help on here. We don't want to help them cheat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick and dirty, this will do the trick:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var year = (new Date()).getFullYear(), select = document.getElementById("year"), option = null, next_year = null;
    for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        option = document.createElement("option");
        next_year = parseInt(year, 10) + i;
        option.value = next_year;
        option.innerHTML = next_year;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok im trying your code seems to work...:-|

Comment: It works fine, I'm curious as to why the confusion... just put this in your `HEAD` section or include it in an external file and it will handle everything as requested.

Comment: Oh yes its working, jump ,but a critical question will this work all the time , means if suppose users browser is not supporting javascript then (like in case of mobile where it cant be sure that javascript is enabled)

Comment: Well then you would have to use some form of side server language; like PHP or JSP. You asked for a JavaScript solution and I provided.

Comment: ya i got that,ok , but thanks once again :-)

Comment: how would you set one of them as selected?

Answer (score 0):

Untesteded code:

```
function populateYears( nbrOfYears, divID ) {
  var id = document.getElementById( divID );
  var dt = new Date();
  var yr = dy.getFullYear();
  var opt;
  for( var x=0; x<= nbrOfYears; x++ ) {
    opt = new Option( yr, yr );
    id.appendChild( opt );
    yr++;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but i m newbie to this can you tell me how i call this function on page load